# With Coq Proof General, Emacs executes on every period. How do I stop it?

Tags: emacs, coq, proof-general

I'm using Proof General in Emacs on Aquamacs and every time I write a period (".") everything is executed (up to that period). It seems like an electric behavior but it's not. All other keys behave normally.

I know that this is some mode that started when I accidentally used some keybinding. If I restart the session the effect will stop, but I would like to know the keybinding to make it stop (or to make it start).

Do you know what this mode is called? I can't even find it online.

Comment: What major mode (a programming language mode, usually) are you in?

Comment: I'm using Proof General to run Coq.

Comment: What do you get when you run `M-x describe-mode`?

Comment: Thanks Dan! I didn't know you could do that. The mode was 'proof-electric-terminator'. Toggled with C-c terminator-toggle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if you're stuck in a minor mode that you don't know the name of, you can run:

```
M-x describe-mode
```

This will list all currently active major and minor modes, with a description of each. From this, you should be able to figure out which one you need to deactivate.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. 

The mode was 
"proof-electric-terminator"
Toggled with
C-c terminator-character
Read more:
http://proofgeneral.inf.ed.ac.uk/htmlshow.php?title=Proof+General+user+manual&file=releases%2FProofGeneral%2Fdoc%2FProofGeneral%2FProofGeneral_3.html

Comment: Short answer is: press `C-c .`

Comment: Exactly what Clément said.